# How to add data from Firestore into local List in futter

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dart, local

***Flutter***

I am trying to add a `docs & data` from a collection in Firestore into the local List

I have done this but when it print data it display [Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'] in console , i expected to print data info so i can use this List in others Purposes , How can i add real info into this List as same as what it exist in this collection

```
 List  data= [] ;
Future addData() async {
        QuerySnapshot  val = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.documentUid).collection(widget.collectionName).get();
        setState(() {
          data.add(val);
        });
        print(data) ;
      }
```

Comment: Can you add what was the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `async/await`, you don't have to use `.then`.

Update your code to this below:

```
Future addData() async {
  QuerySnapshot val = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.documentUid).collection(widget.collectionName).get();

  setState(() {
    data.addAll(val.docs.map((var documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.data()).toList());
  });
}
```

I added [.docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html) to the `images.addAll(val.docs)` line as that is the way to get the list of query document snapshots from a query snapshot.

You can print the data in the query document snapshots by calling `.data()` like this:

```
  val.docs.forEach((var documentSnapshot) {
      print(documentSnapshot.data());
  });
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't add any data , it's only print [Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'] in console , i expected to print the data info so i can use them

Comment: same result but it print [Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot' 5 times' which is the same number in that collection with no any real info

Comment: it's work perfectly !! , thanks Eronmosele , truly ! but what if i need to add data to that List then print ? in the same

Comment: You will have to map the values from the list into the data object. Check out the updated answer.